# How to parse variable in REXX/Regina

Tags: rexx

When writing a macro, I have a variable, {$#2}, that either starts with a 1 or 2 digit number followed by a ".", or it doesn't. When it starts in that way, I want to put the number into a rexxvar, which I have called C.

I have tried

```
#if [ DATATYPE(LEFT({$#2},1), "W") ]                             \
#evaluate ^^ ^parse '{$#2} C '.' .^                              \
#endif                                                           \
```

This, and every variation I can think of, gives errors saying the #IF line contains invalid characters.

How should I do this?

I am using PPWizard, and Regina - but I can't create either tag.

Thanks
Ian

Comment: Is it the if that is causing the problem ??? or the parse statement or both ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **do not** use **PPWizard** so this could all be wrong, but

Looking at [PPWizard #if](http://dennisbareis.com/ppwizard/hashif.htm), the if should be either

```
#if DATATYPE(LEFT({$#2},1), "W")
```

or

```
#if [ DATATYPE(LEFT({$#2},1), "W") <> 0 ]
```

But I do not know wether you can imbed the {$#2} or not (I do not know PPWizard)

---

For the parse statement one of these may be what you want

```
#evaluate ^^ ^parse value '{$#2}' with C '.' .^
```

or

```
#evaluate ^^ ^parse var {$#2} C '.' .^
```

See [rexx parse syntax](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r12/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r12.ikjc300/ikj4c31061.htm)

---

An alternative way might try the [Define Rexx](http://dennisbareis.com/ppwizard/hashdefinerexx.htm) tag and do it in rexx. More people could help you with pure rexx. i.e the rexx would be

```
if  DATATYPE(LEFT(value_to_process,1), "W") then do
    parse var value_to_process C '.'
end
```

where value_to_process is the value to be checked (i.e. {$#2})

Answer (score 0):

For others. 
The final answer to the problem is to write

```
#RexxVar value_to_process = {$#2}  
#evaluate+ ^^ ^if  DATATYPE(LEFT(value_to_process,1), "W") then do; parse var value_to_process  C '.'; end^  \
```

in the macro I was creating.

Thanks Bruce. Your reply was most helpful on my route to a solution.